# Расширение на js

Tags: javascript

Хочу написать расширение для браузера, чтобы оно решало все задания само.
Нужен просто скрипт, который меняет

```
<input type="radio" name="radio-0" checkit="">
```

на

```
<input type="radio" name="radio-0" checkit="true">
```

по всех странице.
`type` и `name` могут быть разными, поэтому нужно их как-то игнорировать.

Comment: Если честно в _js_ почти не шарю, однако описание проблемы сильно смахивает на то, что необходимо использовать _regEx'ы_, просто написав так, чтоб он находил элементы с любым `type` и `name`

Comment: @Dafter находить DOM-элементы с помощью regEx'ов невозможно

Comment: @andreymal окей, прошу прощения, я и указал, что не особо уверен в своем ответе.

Comment: Хотите написать расширение для браузера **ВЫ**,  но не шарите и нужно написать скрипт **НАМ**. Логика железная

Comment: "выбирая этот чекбокс вы подтверждаете передачу своей жизни нам.." и ваше расширение делает `true`. Не задумывались, почему таких расширений до сих пор нет? И да.. Что за атрибут `checkit`?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Возможно это то, что Вам и нужно.
Данный скрипт перебирает все найденные input и добавляет им атрибут checkit="true".

```js
var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input');

for (i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
  inputs[i].setAttribute('checkit', 'true');
}
```

```html
<input type="text"><br>
<input type="submit"><br>
<input type="checkbox"><br>
<input type="radio"><br>
<input type="text">
```